# How do I Insert a Unicode text by ADOQuery into a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, unicode

I'm going to insert a Unicode text into SQL Server database by ADOQuery .
My text is stored in `k_message` *WideChar* variable.
I know that I have to prefix 'N' for Unicode actions in SQL Server,
But in this case How to apply this letter for `k_message` column? 
on the other hand ADOQuery only gets non-Unicode text SQL string
and I have to use parameter instead.
With the following code I have received error:

> Incorrect Syntax near @P1.

My Programming Environment is: Borland C++ Builder 6

```
txt="insert my_table(ksource,ksubject,kdate,ktime,kmessage) values ('SMS','"+
                                              fsubject+"','"+
                                              fdate+"','"+
                                              ftime+"',N :k_message)";
DMod1->ADOQuery2->Close();
DMod1->ADOQuery2->Prepared=true;
DMod1->ADOQuery2->SQL->Clear();
DMod1->ADOQuery2->SQL->Add(txt);
DMod1->ADOQuery2->Parameters->ParamByName("k_message")->Value=k_message;
DMod1->ADOQuery2->ExecSQL();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
txt="insert my_table(ksource,ksubject,kdate,ktime,kmessage) values ('SMS',N'"+
                                              fsubject+"',N'"+
                                              fdate+"',N'"+
                                              ftime+"N',N :k_message)";
```

Comment: Please change `"N',N` to `"',N` ;).

Comment: It helped me . Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250491/handling-of-unicode-characters-using-delphi-6